# Media Queries breaking At Wrong Widths

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have one rule for media queries

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1080px) {
```

I know 1080 is a weird number this was just for test...

That being said, when I resize my page, the background color (what I'm using to test the visualization of the breakpoint) changes when the width of the page is 1190px.

What is the reason this is happening, and how can I fix it?

Thanks

*Update* has anyone else heard of this happening?  I'm using Semanitc UI, not sure if that has anything to do with this issue, I still haven't resolved it.

Comment: Speculation: You have a 10 pixel wide scrollbar.

Comment: the difference is close to 100px;

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1190px) {
      your CSS
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of why this might help to your answer.

Comment: With this BG color changes at 1310px.  Same problem, different numbers.